# how to get atr value at particular price or time frame in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

if we want to see atr we can just plot the graph of atr on any security it will show it

//@version=4
study("My Script")

plot(atr(14))

but if i want to calculate atr value at particular price pro-grammatically in this case 
i want to calculate atr value at previous pivot low then how to get it in pine?
please help[image]

suppose in this chart at pivot low of 5152.45 atr is 76.65 when we move mouse over it, it shows but how to get this into pine
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the value when your script detects the condition where you want to save the ATR from. Understanding [Pine's execution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html) will help you conceptualize the solution, which comes up very often in writing scripts. A Pine script is executed on every bar and so it's much more efficient to save values you will need on following bars whenever you can, rather than wait for the moment where you need the values and then look back to find them.

```
//@version=4
study("Atr at Pivot")
pivotLegs = 3
pHi = pivothigh(pivotLegs, pivotLegs)
atr = atr(14)
var float atrAtHiPivot = na
if not na(pHi)
    // A pivot was detected. Since the pivot actually occurred `pivotLegs` bars back, 
    // fetch atr value from the same number of bars back.
    atrAtHiPivot := atr[pivotLegs]
plotchar(not na(pHi), "not na(pHi)", "▼", location.top)
plot(atrAtHiPivot, "atrAtHiPivot")
plot(atr, "atr", color.aqua)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks PineCoders-LucF actually i want to calculate the value of atr at pivot low and high if you have time please guide me thanks

Comment: You sound like you're looking more for code than guidance ) Supplied the high pivot part in my answer. I'll let you do the low pivots. Note that you seem to be wanting to simulate the pivot detection mechanism from the built-in indicator. Make sure whatever pivot detection code you use in Pine produces the same result as the built-in.

Comment: Thanks Lucf actually i just introduce to pine n i look more on code rather than following a systematic approach i got some links will start learning in systematic way thanks for your help, will update you code asap

Comment: Hi Lucf I have the done low pivots still many things in my mind i followed your website also https://www.pinecoders.com
suppose i am taking some user input through input function and plotting some lines on chart once i move to other symbol still the user input value retain is there any way we can reset it once i switch to different securities or different time frame
thanks for your help

Comment: No, afaik there's no way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
//@version=4
study("Atr at Pivot")
pivotLegs = 3
pHi = pivothigh(pivotLegs, pivotLegs)
atr = atr(14)
var float atrAtHiPivot = na

var float atrAtLoPivot = na
pLo = pivotlow(pivotLegs, pivotLegs)

if not na(pHi)
    // A pivot was detected. Since the pivot actually occurred `pivotLegs` bars back, 
    // fetch atr value from the same number of bars back.
    atrAtHiPivot := atr[pivotLegs]
//curious
if not na(pLo)
    atrAtLoPivot := atr[pivotLegs]

plotchar(not na(pHi), "not na(pHi)", "▼", location.top)
plot(atrAtHiPivot, "atrAtHiPivot")
plot(atr, "atr", color.aqua)
//curious
plotchar(not na(pLo), "not na(pLo)", "▲", location.bottom)
plot(atrAtLoPivot,"atrAtLoPivot")
plot(atr,"atr",color.red)
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdvdq.jpg
```